# Elixir- Receving and sending messges simultaneously with a timeout

Tags: elixir

I am new in Elixir and I am trying to develop peers which send a given number of messages to all other peers. Additionally, there is a specified time after which the node should stop broadcasting and receiving messages. My question is how to make it sending and receiving messages at the same time? And the second problem is how to include a timeout for that. This is my current code:

```
messages_sent = Map.new()
messages_received = Map.new()

receive do
  #Distribute messages
  for dest <- peers, do:
    for i <- 0..max_broadcasts, do: #Max broadcast specifies how many messages send to each peer
        send dest, { :peer_broadcast, self()}
        #Adds peer to map or update if it is already present
        Map.update(messages_sent, dest, 0, &(&1 + 1))
    end
  end

 #Receiving messages
  { :peer_broadcast, peer} -> 
       Map.update(messages_received, peer, 0, &(&1 + 1)) 

end #receive
```

Comment: You need to establish a loop process that refreshes its state over a minimum  interval.That way you can either send or receive each time the loop is traversed. The way you are doing it blocks until all the messages are sent. Take a look at https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/processes.html#state .

Comment: May I ask what is the goal of having this _in the same process_? It would be much easier, fault-tolerant and performant to have a supervisor with two workers, one for sending and one for receiving messages.

Comment: You can not receive and send at the same exact time without concurrency. So I propose you create a process for receiving, and a process for sending.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin by two workers you mean two separate nodes?

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer the problem is that I must have it as a single process

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff could you help me to refractor my current code based on what you've sent me, because I don't know how to include the loop with send function in it

Comment: By two workers I mean two [worker processes](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Supervisor.Spec.html#t:worker/0). You definitely should read about OTP in the first place; many questions will be gone.

Comment: @GrzegorzBrzęczyszczykiewicz
 the input is the list of `peers` and the integer `max_broadcasts` - what is the desired output?